# css - How to prevent to "splitting" div on PDF generating

Tags: css, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating PDF with dynamic fields, e.g. textarea.
At this moment I'm using:

```
    .div__break {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

To prevent splitting this DIV but it's not working and I still see this (content is hiding under `header-html`):
[image]

I'm using WKHTMLTOPDF with Laravel. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you have an other element with `page-break-inside: avoid`.

Probably you can use

```
page-break-inside: avoid !important;
```

instead of

```
page-break-inside: avoid
```